# How print to console or using single quote json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting response like

```
{ Data: "{'id': '1', 'email': 'a@a.com'}", errorMessage:: "" }
```

and i can't print to console or use it anywhere.

```
console.log(response.data.Data)
```

when i wrote it, i'm getting:

```
{ Data: "{'id': '1', 'email': 'a@a.com'}", errorMessage:: "" }
```

but when i wrote:

```
console.log(response.data.Data.email)
```

i'm getting undefined.

so i'm think it's because of single quotes.

i tried `response.data.Data.replace(/\'/g, '"');`

but doesn't work.

how i can access to email in Data ?

Comment: The `Data` property contains a string. It's not even a valid JSON. I suggest you change whatever logic generates that value to be correct.

Comment: That is not valid json. Json uses double quotes.

Comment: Replacing the quotes isn't enough; you need to then call `JSON.parse()` on it in order to turn it into an Object. `response.data.Data = JSON.parse(response.data.Data.replace(/\'/g, '"'))`

Answer (score 2):

`Data` is a string, you'll need to parse it using `JSON.parse`, and you'll need to use double quotes instead of single quotes :

```js
const response = {
  Data: '{"id": "1", "email": "a@a.com"}',
  errorMessage: ""
};

console.log('Before parsing: ', response.Data.email);

response.Data = JSON.parse(response.Data);

console.log('After parsing: ', response.Data.email);
```